# Setting Property Value using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

How do I set my property value from array via reflection in `C#`?

```
public class Employee 
{
   public string Name { get; set; }    
   public int ID { get; set; }    
   public void SetValues(string[] items)
   {

   }
}
```

I need to use `SetValues` method to set property values from items array.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Done any research?  This is not a tutorial site.  Please read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you said you Need to use SetValues(string[] items) {...}, and that you'd have an Employee object such as:

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
```

I believe you're looking for:

```
string[] values = new string[] {"someName", "someID"};
typeof(Employee).GetMethod("SetValues").Invoke(emp, new object[]{ values });
```

Now SetValues would have to convert (in its body) "someID" to int with something like:

```
ID = int.Parse(items[1]);
```